# Use of TABLE_DATE_RANGE function with table decorators

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any any way to use TABLE_DATE_RANGE or TABLE_QUERY with table decorators?

I would like to extract all "new records" (added in past 2 hours) from a set of tables.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently. That's an interesting feature request, however. I'm trying to think of what the syntax would look like. Perhaps where the dataset name / prefix is used we could use a `*`, as in 
`TABLE_DATE_RANGE(dataset1.prefix*@time, timestamp1, timestamp2)` or
`TABLE_QUERY(dataset1.prefix*@time, 'where clause')`

I've filed a feature request.

Comment: Note: Feature was implemented! https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt I don't think feature is implemented yet

Comment: Does this feature not supported yet?